# I dont wanna repeat myself in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a script what made a list of URLs:

```
arr = [['1'], [*'05'..'15'], ['78'], [*'02'..'04', *'07'..'12', 
*'15'..'27'],[*'00000'..'99999']]

file = File.new('./file_300k.txt', 'w')
    combos = arr.first.product(*arr.drop(1)).map(&:join)

comb = combos.first(300000)

comb.each do |n|
 a = n.to_f / 11
 afloat = a.round 1
 str = afloat.to_s.delete(".").reverse
 b = str[0]
 file.puts "https://blablabla.com/company/ul/#{n}#{b}"
end


    file = File.new('./file_301_600k.txt', 'w')
combos = arr.first.product(*arr.drop(1)).map(&:join)
comb = combos[300001..600000]
comb.each do |n|

    a = n.to_f / 11
    afloat = a.round 1
    str = afloat.to_s.delete(".").reverse
    b = str[0]
    file.puts "https://blablabla.com/company/ul/#{n}#{b}"

end
```

...

```
    file = File.new('./file_1__1_3.txt', 'w')
combos = arr.first.product(*arr.drop(1)).map(&:join)
comb = combos.first[1000001..1300000]
comb.each do |n|

    a = n.to_f / 11
    afloat = a.round 1
    str = afloat.to_s.delete(".").reverse
    b = str[0]
    file.puts "blablabla.com/company/ul/#{n}#{b}"

end
```

...

As you can see, I repeat myself, cuse is full results have more than 24 millions combinations, and i need a group of small TXT docs for my point. I think this case could be solve in another way too, but i wanna use OOP decision, cuse i need to understand how OOP works. Thank you!

Comment: What you actually want to do you want to reduce the number of each loop or what please clarify

Comment: Why you are making the each loop for each file read

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The things that change in the repeating code are

- file_name
- range

The object common for the repeating code is

- arr

So to refactor to keep it try you could create a method

```
def build_file(name, range, arr)
  file = File.new("./file_#{name}.txt", 'w')
  combos = arr.first.product(*arr.drop(1)).map(&:join)

  combos[range].each do |n|
    a = n.to_f / 11
    afloat = a.round 1
    str = afloat.to_s.delete(".").reverse
    b = str[0]
    file.puts "https://blablabla.com/company/ul/#{n}#{b}"
  end
  file.close
end
```

Then call it as...

```
build_file('300k',(0..30_000), arr)
build_file('301_600k',(30_001..60_000), arr)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something along those lines? Its untested reduces that you have write the loop again for each 300_000.

```
ITERATE_LIMIT = 300_000

# creates enough files based on the combos count and you iteration limit
# sets @file1, @file2, ....
(combos.count.to_f / ITERATE_LIMIT).to_i.each do |i|
  instance_variable_set("@file#{i}", File.new("./file_#{i}.txt", 'w'))
end

# you regular loop
# selects the file based on the index the loop is currently on and puts the 
# string
comb.each_with_index do |n, index|
  a = n.to_f / 11
  afloat = a.round 1
  str = afloat.to_s.delete(".").reverse
  b = str[0]
  instance_variable_get("@file#{(index.to_f / ITERATE_LIMIT).to_i}").puts "https://blablabla.com/company/ul/#{n}#{b}"
end
```